# Can I unfreeze bash or vim when SSH session freezes from timeout?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, terminal

When my SSH session times out, the whole terminal freezes.

Is there any way to break out of that connection? <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't cut it.

Comment: What about `Alt + SysReq + O`? *(Please note that I am only kidding!)*

Answer (score 60):

You need to send the ssh escape sequence, which by default is <kbd>~</kbd> at the beginning of a line (in other words, preceded by a newline, or enter). Then send the disconnect character, which is <kbd>.</kbd>.

E.g.:

```
host1> ssh host2
Last login: Tue Jun  4 21:56:26 2013 from host1
host2>
```

(host2 freezes, press <kbd>enter</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>)

```
host2> Connection to host2 closed.
host1>
```

See the `ssh(1)` manual:

> -e escape_char
>              Sets the escape character for sessions with a pty (default: ‘~’).
>              The escape character is only recognized at the beginning of a
>              line.  The escape character followed by a dot (‘.’) closes the
>              connection; followed by control-Z suspends the connection; and
>              followed by itself sends the escape character once.  Setting the
>              character to “none” disables any escapes and makes the session
>              fully transparent.

Comment: This answer is amazing

Answer (score 0):

You could kill the ssh process - ie, from another terminal using `kill` or `killall`.

... But Bahamat's way is the better, cleaner way.